# Fundamental Matrices for Linear ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Why is the following statement true?:

For a matrix ODE: $\mathbf{x'=Ax}$ with special fundamental matrix, $\Phi (t)$ or $e^{\mathbf{A}}$, where $\Phi(t_0) = I$, and fundamental matrix containing the general solution, $\Psi (t)$, the following is true:

> $\Psi(t)$ =$\Phi (t) T$, where T contains columns that are linearly independent eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$.

This equation comes from the statements: $e^\mathbf{A} =TQ(t)T^{-1}$ and $\Psi (t) = TQ$, where Q is a diagonal matrix with $e^{\lambda t}$ along its diagonal, where the $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$.  In addition, it seems to conclude, by the process of diagonalization of a matrix, that the eigenvectors/values of $\mathbf{A}$ are the same as those of $e^{\mathbf{A}}$.

Thanks.